# Lost table in Google Cloud SQL - MySQL error code 1813. How can I recreate it?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

I'm having an issue with one of our databases hosted on Google Cloud SQL.

If I issue the command

```
SHOW TABLES
```

as root the table is not listed and if I try to create the table it causes an error:

```
Error Code: 1813. Tablespace for table '`db`.`the_table`' exists. Please DISCARD the tablespace before IMPORT.
```

If I try to select from the table it says:

```
Error Code: 1146. Table 'db.tha_table' doesn't exist
```

When I search the web, common solutions are to modify the .ibd files etc. The problem is I don't have access to the file system on Google Cloud SQL.

Any ideas about how to delete the table from the tablespace and recreate it?

We tried to reboot the cloud SQL instance but no luck.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Please email your instance name, with the timeline of what happened to cloud-sql@google.com, specifically when you created the table and when you discovered that the table was gone, etc.

Please put the link of this stackoverflow question in your email for reference purpose, thanks.

Comment: @Herman Thank you! I did so but got a auto reply saying "....'cloud-sql@google.com' is not an official support channel...". Will I still get a reply or what should I do?

Comment: Somebody will look at it.

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason is your database crashed when you run an alter table command, what happened then was mysql deleted the table entry however it didn't reach the step to remove the file on disk.

One possible solution is to create another table with the exact same schema but a different name, after creation, rename that table to the name you use in the original table.